Why was this question closed and upvoted?
This question was closed for being off-topic. It also has 7 upvotes. How does it have that many upvotes if it's not on topic and was closed?

Obviously, it is impossible to tell exactly why people decided to upvote the question - for a start, we don't know who upvoted, yet alone their reasons.
However, some possible reasons include:

For people not familiar with the community consensus that resource recommendation questions are off-topic, the question may seem useful and a good fit for the site.
As such, while the question was still open, people may have upvoted it having found it interesting.
Alternatively, some people may upvote questions that aren't blatantly off topic for the sake of rewarding question askers.
Most of the votes were cast before the post was closed (the question timeline shows that only one vote was cast after closure). The lack of votes after the closure of the post suggests that once people realise a post is off-topic they no longer find it useful or interesting.

